# is it possible to create serverless architecture for this goal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

i have multiple domains like

```
x.static.abc.com
y.static.abc.com
z.static.abc.com
```

i want to use Route53 & cloudfront & s3 to serve static contents.

when a request sent to **x.static.abc.com/1.png** i need to soft rewrite it to **abc.com/static/x/1.png**.

i dont want redirect request with 301 and 302 response. so i dont want to use Redirection Rules in S3 under Enable website hosting option.

is there any way to do it ? I need your solutions or advices.
Thanks all.

**edit:** 
i use Route53 & cloudfront & s3,  more than 4 years. this question is not about basics like "how can i define DNS settings in rout53".

i created bucket in S3 named with x.static.abc.com, 
enabled website hosting settings in properties, 
i added endpoint to Route53 and added Routing Rules to redirection rule like:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>..</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyWith>...</ReplaceKeyWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

but this is not what i am looking for. Because it redirects requests with 301 or 302.

i am looking for an option like cloudflare's :

> Resolve Override (Enterprise Only): Changes the origin address for the
>   request to the URL. Users will see the domain name in the browser
>   address bar, but content will be served from the URL in the resolve
>   field.
>   https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But the approach has a significant disadvantage - you should not use static.abc.com but preferable a separate domain. Why? Cookies ;)

Comment: great news, how can i do that?

Comment: Learning the basics of the technology you use would help. Otherwise hire someone. We are a Q&A site, not a "do my work for me for free" site.

Comment: in my opinion this is not the basics, this is an advanced usecase. thanks for reply anyway.

Comment: Your question "how" would mostly include basics such as how to set up domain names in DNS. Also we answer SPECIFIC technical questions. If you are unable to get started reading the documentation, imho, you should not touch a computer but flip burgers. Do not be lazy - start reading the documentation, then ask specific questions for things you do not understand.

Comment: I agree with the "basics" assessment for the most part, though "origin path" is a setting that many users seem to either overlook or assume it means something different than it does, and this is the first time I recall seeing a question where that appeared to be an essential part of the solution. Of course, with CloudFront's ability to strip cookies, they still take up bandwidth but don't need to interfere with cacheability.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with HAProxy on EC2 would be trivial, but if we are constrained to only using AWS-managed offerings, here is the closest you can get (and it seems pretty close):

Create a CloudFront distribution with the following configuration:

- alternate domain name for the distribution set to x.static.example.com
- origin server example.com with origin path (on the same screen as the origin server, *not* to be confused with the path pattern in the cache behavior) set to `/static/x`
- default cache behavior forwards to the origin server but is configured *not* to whitelist the `Host:` header
- map x.static.example.com in Route 53 to the new CloudFront distribution.

The net effect of this configuration is that the incoming host header, once recognized and used to map the request to this distribution, is discarded, and the origin host's hostname will be sent as the host header.

Original request coming into CloudFront:

```
GET /images/lolcat.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: x.static.example.com
```

Request sent from CloudFront to the origin server:

```
GET /static/x/images/lolcat.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Seems legit.

You would need one of these for each hostname, because there is no provision for dynamic mapping, but CloudFront doesn't charge for the existence of a distribution -- only the traffic -- so, no harm, there.   I think the above makes for a pretty straightforward solution.